# Yii CGridView can't show custom SQL attribute

Tags: php, yii

In the `Type` model's `search()` function, I want to display three attributes in CGridview:

`type.name`, `type.description` and `count(dataset_type.dataset_id)`

```
public function search()
{
    // Warning: Please modify the following code to remove attributes that
    // should not be searched.

    $criteria=new CDbCriteria;
            $criteria->alias='t';
            $criteria->select='t.name, t.description, count(dataset_type.dataset_id) as number';
            $criteria->join='LEFT JOIN dataset_type ON dataset_type.type_id=t.id';
            $criteria->group='t.id';


    return new CActiveDataProvider($this, array(
        'criteria'=>$criteria,
    ));
}
```

This is the view:

```
<?php $this->widget('zii.widgets.grid.CGridView', array(
    'id' => 'type-grid',
    'dataProvider' => $model->search(),
    'filter' => $model,
    'itemsCssClass' => 'table table-bordered',
    'columns' => array(
        'name',
        'description',
        'number',
        array(
            'class'=>'CButtonColumn',
        ),
    ),
)); ?>
```

but in this way the columns in CGridView can only display model attributes, it shows `type.number` can't find in model `Type`, how can I display the `count()`?

Comment: yes , i forgot add. thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will also have to add the attribute to your model to be able to use it as a column in your CGridView:

```
class Type extends CActiveRecord {

    public $number;
```